# Autoconf: Check if a program in an unsupported language compiles

Tags: build, autotools, autoconf, configure

To conditionally enable a part of an autotooled project, I need to check whether a short program stub in a language not supported by autotools out of the box compiles or not.

I need something like `AC_TRY_COMPILE` with an arbitrary compiler executable – create a temporary file, write a piece of code to it, and try if invoking the compiler (found via `AC_CHECK_PROGS` before) returns an exit code equal to zero or not.

What is the most elegant/common way to do this?

Comment: I think you might have to write your own macro, based on `AC_TRY_COMPILE`. Also try the Autoconf Archive, maybe someone else has written it: http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AC_TRY_COMPILE` (which is deprecated and replaced by [`AC_COMPILE_IFELSE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Running-the-Compiler.html#Running-the-Compiler)) only supports a limited set of languages: C, C++, Fortran 77, Fortran, Erlang, Objective C, Objective C++ ([source](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Language-Choice.html#Language-Choice)).

`configure.ac` can contain custom shell code - it just gets skipped over by `autoconf` (really `m4`). Why not just write your test in shell? If you're going to use more than one test, wrap it in an [`AC_DEFUN`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Macro-Definitions.html#index-AC_005fDEFUN-1585).

Comment: That's what I actually ended up doing; I just forgot to write up the answer here and mark it as accepted – thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To enable an optional part of an autotooled project, you should use an `--enable-something` option.  Don't make it dependent on what is currently available in the build environment.  That is prone to mask errors in automated builds.  (Example: Linux distributions have been known to ship crippled packages because of a missing build dependencies or other problem in the environment, where raising an error would have been more helpful than proceeding silently.)